# How to retrive my connection's information from Linkedin via REST api

Tags: rest, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

I want to get my Linkedin connetion's information through REST apis (list of names of my connection's),
but i am not able to find any methods to do so. currently i am able to retrieve only my information. Could any one please help me how can i do so.

additionally, i am looking for the API which will help me to send Inmail/msg to my connections.

Answer (score 0):

That's because no such functions exist in LinkedIn's API. This is strange, but true.